# Why are values stored in an NVARCHAR column sometimes padded with trailing spaces?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005

An app I'm working on is storing Unicode strings in an `NVARCHAR(50)` column in an SQL Server 2005 database.

Sometimes, the database returns a string padded with spaces up to the max length of the column (50). At other times the padding doesn't happen.

I think that the type of this column was originally specified as `NCHAR`, but that when we realized the spaces were being added, we changed it to `NVARCHAR(50)`. Could this have anything to do with it?

Either way, can this 'feature' be turned off?

**Clarification**

I just realized that what I wrote above doesn't make it clear that even newly-inserted strings are getting padded with spaces.

Comment: This post has a very detailed answer - [Behavior of Varchar with spaces at the end](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/10510/101434)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

NCHAR pads the field, NVARCHAR doesn't. But if the data is from the old field then the spaces will remain until trimmed.

Comment: Right, which is why we changed it to NVARCHAR, but the issue persists. :(

Comment: Use an update statement like others have suggested: Update MyTable Set MyColumn = LTRIM(RTRIM(MyColumn));

Comment: What I meant is that even though we changed the column to NVARCHAR ages ago, newly-inserted strings are still getting padded.

Comment: One solution could be to create a new table with nvarchar and do a SELECT INTO statement to copy the data from the old table into the new one using trim functions on the padded columns as you do it. Hopefully this should lose the padding. Maybe how you are inserting the values is adding the padding somehow too.

Comment: @dandan78 are your `INSERT`s being performed, say, by a stored procedure which accepts the values as `NCHAR(50)` rather than `NVARCHAR(50)`? If the value gets padded at some point, it bet it will stay padded when implicitly converted to `NVARCHAR(50)`.

Comment: @binki Unfortunatley, I cannot check, but that could easily have been the case since we generally did use stored procedures in such cases.

Answer (score 9):

The "legacy" spaces caused by the nchar type previously persist because of [SET ANSI_PADDING ON](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187403.aspx) which is the default.

You need to UPDATE with an RTRIM to remove trailing spaces.

Answer (score 7):

If you have converted them previously from `NCHAR` to `NVARCHAR`, any data that was previously entered will still contain the trailing spaces. You can update them all by:

```
UPDATE tablename
SET column = RTRIM(column)
```

Comment: nvarchar is needed for unicode strings (2 bytes per character). If you need unicode characters then use nvarchar but obviously it will take up more space to do so.

Comment: Ouch, that was quick on the downvote. I've corrected the false information I originally put.

Comment: No, I guessed it wasn't you, but whoever did downvote was quick - and no comment on why either... never mind.

Answer (score 3):

You can sometimes do this:

```
Update MyTable Set MyColumn = LTRIM(RTRIM(MyColumn));
```

Answer (score 2):

How are you getting the values into the table? I think it's possible that if you have a stored proc and you explicitly set the length of the parameter that updates this column to 50 (say via SqlCommand), it will end up padding it on the ADO.NET side already.

Comment: Hm, that's a good point. I'm going to have to get back to you on that.

Comment: Came here via Google search for `nvarchar padded spaces`, and this was my issue. Database script was NVARCHAR(50), but the model had set the field to Fixed Lenght = True. Nice catch!

Answer (score 1):

`NCHAR` columns are padded with spaces because `CHARACTER` is a fixed-width datatype as required by `SQL` standard:

> If `VARYING` is not specified in `<character string type>`, then
>                 the length in characters of the character string is fixed and
>                 is the value of `<length>`.

and

> Let `T` and `V` be a `TARGET` and `VALUE` specified in an application of
>               this `Subclause`
>
> …
>
> If the data type of `T`is fixed-length character string with
>                 length in characters `L` and the length in characters `M` of `V`
>                 is less than `L`, then the first `M` characters of `T` are set to `V`
>                 and the last `L-M` characters of `T` are set to `<space>`s.

Note that `ANSI_PADDING = ON` (which is default) functions and expressions other than concatenation and comparison implicitly truncate the trailing spaces on `VARCHAR` arguments:

```
SELECT  LEN(a), LEN(b), LEN(a + b)
FROM    (
        VALUES
        (CAST('a ' AS VARCHAR(100)), CAST('b' AS VARCHAR(100)))
        ) AS q(a, b)

-----------
1    1    3
```

Comment: I read the docs about NVARCHAR on MSDN and apparently not only is ANSI_PADDING ON by default, it cannot be turned off. That is truly annoying.

Answer (score 1):

I came across this thread while trying to solve this exact same problem and will post my solution.

I had used NChar as this is my first SQL database and I didn't know about the padded spaces. I then created a LINQ-to-SQL class to provide access to my database. When I later updated my database I didn't update my LINQ-to-SQL class so it still had NChar in the code behind. I changed them to fix the problem.

If you didn't use this exact method you may have a similar solution for your method. Something you use to add records hasn't been updated.

Comment: Thanks, that helped me. If you have a tt file for database first, run the tt after the database change. Also, don't forgot to update the existing values in the database by running a UPDATE table SET column = RTRIM(column)