# SQL Server Strings Padded with Whitespace on Insert - why?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqldatatypes

when i tried to insert some data into the SQL Server there was these extra characters

for example my `textBox1.text == "SAMPLE"`
then this was the code

```
string qry = "insert into FinalImages (FinalImageName, Date) values(@FinalImageName, @Date)";

SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection(c_string);
//Initialize SqlCommand object for insert
SqlCommand SqlCom = new SqlCommand(qry, c);

SqlCom.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@FinalImageName", SqlDbType.Char, 40)).Value = textBox1.Text;
SqlCom.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Date", SqlDbType.Char, 40)).Value = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

but when i check in the tables the record was this `"SAMPLE                             "`, it has *34* space characters added
what should be wrong?

Comment: You have won the prize for worst title of the week.

Comment: Related post - [Why are values stored in an NVARCHAR column sometimes padded with trailing spaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5746143/465053)

Answer (score 17):

Don't use SqlDbType.Char, use NVarChar. Char is a fixed-size string, padded with spaces (a terrible monster).

Answer (score 8):

You chose `CHAR(40)` as the parameter type. You meant `VARCHAR(40)`.

Answer (score 7):

You're using `char(40)`. This way you will always have a string with a length of 40. If it's shorter, the SQL-Server will automatically fill the rest with spaces.
Char is normally only used for a fixed length of data, e.g. CustomerNumbers

You want to use `varchar(40)` in this case to get a variable length.

Answer (score 1):

You are specifying that the parameter is 40 characters long and not variable length:

```
SqlCom.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@FinalImageName", SqlDbType.Char, ***40***)).Value = textBox1.Text;
```

So it is helpfully padding the value that you provided.

Just use the overload that doesn't take the length parameter, and uses VarChar:

```
SqlCom.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@FinalImageName", SqlDbType.VarChar)).Value = textBox1.Text;
```

Answer (score 0):

Run

> SET ANSI_PADDING OFF;
>
> GO

further comprehensive information is [SET ANSI_PADDING](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-ansi-padding-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

If you do this you will need to update all existing records to remove the padding with ltrim()/rtrim() as turning padding off will not affect existing records
[RTRIM (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rtrim-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)