# Why the SQL Server ignore the empty space at the end automatically?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I wrote a query

```
SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserName = 'admin '
```

by mistaken typing. But I found that the result is as the same as

```
SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserName = 'admin'
```

It seems that the empty space at the end is ignored by SQL Server automatically.

Can anybody tell me why?

FYI, the column `UserName` is of type `nvarchar(MAX)`.

Comment: Related post - [Why are values stored in an NVARCHAR column sometimes padded with trailing spaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5746143/465053)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

SQL Server is following the ANSI/ISO standard for string comparison.

The article [How SQL Server Compares Strings with Trailing Spaces](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316626) explains this in detail.

> SQL Server follows the ANSI/ISO SQL-92 specification... on how to
>   compare strings with spaces. The ANSI standard requires padding for
>   the character strings used in comparisons so that their lengths match
>   before comparing them. The padding directly affects the semantics of
>   WHERE and HAVING clause predicates and other Transact-SQL string
>   comparisons. For example, Transact-SQL considers the strings 'abc' and
>   'abc ' to be equivalent for most comparison operations.

Also, as explained in the article, if you compare with `LIKE` you do **not** get this behaviour.

Comment: Of course comparing with `LIKE` does not test for equality, so the next natural question is [How can I make SQL Server return FALSE for comparing varchars with and without trailing spaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29108892/1026)

Comment: So essentially, when you compare two strings of different length, the shorter string is padded with spaces to the length of the longer string?  I had never imagined.  I thought for a moment a schrödinbug in my company's software had been activated whereby strings were getting a spurious trailing space, but it turns out this was making no difference and the bug I was seeing was for a different reason.

Answer (score 7):

If you are trying like this

```
SELECT * 
FROM Users 
WHERE UserName = 'admin '
```

empty spaces are ignored SQL Server. But if you try like this

```
SELECT * 
FROM Users 
WHERE UserName Like 'admin '
```

It consider the empty spaces also.

```
DECLARE @Person1 varchar(50)='admin'
SELECT 1  WHERE @Person1 = 'admin '
SELECT 1  WHERE @Person1 like 'admin '
```

The result of the above query set is

[image]

Comment: sql server only ignores trailing whitespace, not leading whitespace