# Blank Spaces are Not Including IN Variable

Tags: sql-server

Actually I'm validating the User_Name With the Column user_Name which Present in a table.

User `vipul_1` Present in table, But if pass The data, 'vipul_1 ', it Should return 0 rows affected but instead of this return me the Result.

```
 DECLARE @User_Name    NVARCHAR(25)
    SET @User_Name= 'vipul_1       '
```

Answer (score 1):

***`Returns the number of characters of the specified string expression, excluding trailing blanks.`*** This is clearly mentioned **[`here`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190329(SQL.90).aspx)**.

Trailing blanks won't be included in the length count. But it will include the blanks in the beginning of the string.

For example.

```
DECLARE @User_Name as NVARCHAR(25)
SET @User_Name= 'vipul_1       '
SELECT  LEN(@User_Name)[User_Name]
```

This will return `7`.

But,

```
DECLARE @User_Name as NVARCHAR(25)
SET @User_Name= '     vipul_1       '
SELECT  LEN(@User_Name)[User_Name];
```

This will return `12` including the blanks in the beginning.

And if you want to count the trailing spaces also, then just add any character to the end and find the length and subtract `1`.

Something like this.

**Query**

```
declare @username as varchar(1000);
set @username = 'some_name_here     '; -- you are unknown about the content of string.
set @username = @username + '_'; 
select LEN(@username) - 1 as [name_length];
```

**[Find a fiddle demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/68b32/1208)**

Comment: Actually I'm validating the User_Name With the Column  user_Name Present in A Table.User vipul_1 Present in Table But IF pass The data 'vipul_1       ' It Should return 0 rows affected but instead of this return me the Result..

Comment: @AlfaizAhmed : You comment above is totally different from your question.

Comment: @AlfaizAhmed : That means, you want to check the availability of `username` in that table, right?

Comment: Yes whatever I pass In Variable(Might Include blank at the end as I mention) It Should match with Table Column.if not matching it should Return 0 rows Affected.

Comment: @AlfaizAhmed : For that, why do you want to find the length of the string?

Answer (score 0):

he trailing spaces are there. They are just ignored by the LEN function. Try using DATALENGTH function instead.

```
DECLARE @User_Name NVARCHAR(25);
SET @User_Name = 'vipul_1       ';
SELECT
    LenVal = LEN(@User_Name),
    DataLenVal = DATALENGTH(@User_Name);
```

Results...

```
LenVal      DataLenVal
----------- -----------
7           28
```

Answer (score 0):

In Sqlserver [RTRIM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rtrim-transact-sql) and [LTRIM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/ltrim-transact-sql) function exist, use it

```
select LTRIM( ' vipul_1 ') , RTRIM( ' vipul_1  ') , RTRIM(  LTRIM( ' vipul_1 ') )
```

As the latest Sqlserver introduce the [Trim](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/trim-transact-sql) function

**Updated**

SQL Server follows the ANSI/ISO SQL-92 specification, see this below links. For this you compare the string with `LIKE` operator as suggested below.

**Len** function is also not work, use **DATALENGTH**  instead of this (As last suggested).

[Why the SQL Server ignore the empty space at the end automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17876478/why-the-sql-server-ignore-the-empty-space-at-the-end-automatically)

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10510/behavior-of-varchar-with-spaces-at-the-end

```
Declare @table table (name varchar(50))

insert into @table values ('vipul_1'), ('ajay_1') , ('eeee_1') , ('vipul')

DECLARE @User_Name    NVARCHAR(25)
    SET @User_Name= 'vipul_1       '

if Exists (select * from @table where name  = @User_Name and DATALENGTH(name) = DATALENGTH(@User_Name) )
    Select 0
Else
    Select 1

select * from @table where name  like @User_Name
select * from @table where name  = @User_Name
select  * from @table where name  = @User_Name and DATALENGTH(name) = DATALENGTH(@User_Name) --use DataLength for this
```

Comment: I'm passing a User  'vipul_1       ' Which is not Present in Table But User 'vipul_1' is presented. Now If I pass  'vipul_1       '  it should not return any Output as no data Present in Table..

Comment: I don't wan't to Trim the blank space I wan't it to Get Included in Variable which I'm passing as I Mention Above

Comment: let me undrestand, if data exist then what you want and if data not exist , then what you want. give me example as output

Comment: Select * from table_User WHERE Name='vipul_1       ' here it will return me 0 rows.because In Table 'vipul_1' is presented

Comment: that is right and understand, but in this case what you want.

Comment: 0 rows should be affected

Comment: Thanks Buddy But Still find the same I don't to go for Like Operator.it should be = only I need to Validate Password also in same Process