# How to use IN condition in SQL Server when comparing Varchars with trailing spaces?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Here is a sample of the issue:

```
SELECT 'True'
WHERE 'Hello      ' IN ('Hello', 'Goodbye', 'Hello  ')
```

Currently this returns 'True' because SQL ignores trailing spaces when comparing VARCHAR. In [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17876478/why-the-sql-server-ignore-the-empty-space-at-the-end-automatically), this can be solved by using LIKE, however this won't work with an IN condition.

How can I ensure that the comparison takes into account the trailing spaces, ***specifically*** when using the IN condition?

Edit:
My list of acceptable values **can** include items with trailing spaces. Looking to compare exact values essentially (i.e 'Hello ' won't match with 'Hello   ')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a non-space char to the end of your search temrs:

```
DECLARE @Terminator char(1) = '|';

SELECT 'True'
WHERE 'Hello      ' + @Terminator  IN ('Hello' + @Terminator , 'Goodbye' + @Terminator)
```

This will force the comparison to take into account the trailing spaces while keeping everything seargable. (I assume you want to use columns either on the left or on the right side of the `IN` operator)

Comment: This is a good solution, one downside would be that I would have to add the terminator to each of items which I'd like to avoid if possible (I have a long list). Also trying to avoid putting that list into a table

Comment: @Mackija Don't avoid putting the values in a table. I think this will be the correct course of action.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your list of acceptable values do **not** have trailing spaces, perhaps you could use:

```
SELECT 'True'
WHERE 'Hello      ' IN ('Hello', 'Goodbye') AND 'Hello      ' NOT LIKE '% '
```

Comment: Good solution but unfortunately my list does have the potential to have those trailing spaces, I will update my question

Answer (score 1):

I can think of this solution on top of my head:

```
SELECT 'True'
WHERE reverse('Hello      ') IN (reverse('Hello'), reverse('Goodbye'))
```

Basically this forces to compare string using `reverse` function.

But Zohar's solution below is most performance driven solution.

```
SELECT 'True'
WHERE 'Hello      '+'|' IN ('Hello'+'|', 'Goodbye'+'|')
```

Comment: Also a good solution like Zohar's but has a similar problem with having to add something to each of the items in the IN which I can hopefully avoid

Comment: @Mackija : True. But using `LIKE` will most certainly destroy your performance

Comment: Good point, I would say for my purposes though performance isn't a huge issue. More so looking for a solution that is small and readable (if one exists that is)

Comment: If there are spaces at the front, this won't work for the same reason it currently won't work unreversed.

Comment: True, one work around to that would be to do the comparison both reversed and not reversed

Comment: @UnhandledExcepSean : True, but OP has explicitly mentioned in edit about trailing spaces.

Comment: @Mackija Except it still won't work if there are spaces on both sides of the IN.

Comment: @UnhandledExcepSean Right because then I would have to do one on one comparisons like ' Hi  ' = ' Hi  ' OR '  iH ' = '  iH ' outside of the IN

Comment: @PrabhatG To clarify yes I'm only looking at trailing spaces for my case