# Perform exact search honouring spaces

Tags: sql-server, linq-to-entities

I'm using SQL Server 2017 and my collation is `SQL_LATIN1_GENERAL_CP1_CI_AS` and `ANSI_PADDING` is default value (`ON`).

In my table, one of the columns is of type `NVARCHAR(255)` and one of the values is inserted like this (including space):

```
N'abc '
```

And when I search it without space (`N'abc'`), I don't want to get `N'abc '`, but it finds it.

I know I can remove spaces during inserting record, but can't change already inserted records.

How can I prevent to find it with querying like this?

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp (c1 nvarchar(255))

INSERT INTO #tmp 
VALUES (N'abc ')

SELECT * 
FROM #tmp 
WHERE c1 = N'abc'

DROP TABLE #tmp
```

I also found this article but want to prevent while when I querying it.

[Why the SQL Server ignore the empty space at the end automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17876478/why-the-sql-server-ignore-the-empty-space-at-the-end-automatically)

I'm using Linq-to-entities with C#, and with SQL query, I can search with 'LIKE' keyword without percent character

```
SELECT * 
FROM #tmp 
WHERE c1 LIKE N'abc'
```

But with Linq, I don't know how to write this query:

```
entity.Temp.Where(p => p.c1 == "abc");
entity.Temp.Where(p => p.c1.Equals("abc"));
entity.Temp.Where(p => p.c1.Contains("abc"));
```

Comment: Sorry, i didn't describe my situation more about LinqToEntity, so I added it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
SELECT * FROM #tmp WHERE cast(c1 as varbinary(510)) = cast(N'abc' as varbinary(510))
```

This would be very slow if you have a lot of rows, but it works.

Comment: Hi David. Thanks for suggestion. but "SELECT * FROM #tmp WHERE c1 LIKE N'abc'" works what I want, but what really I need is how can I express this for Linq-to-entity