# Weird LINQ ToList(), IEnumerable vs AsQueryable() results

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

So I have this query on MSSQL where BANKS is a `Table View`

```sql
SELECT t.*
  FROM [DB].[dbo].[BANKS] t
  where t.BCODE = 'xxxxxx    '; <--- with spaces
```

which above query has 1 result `BCODE : "xxxxxx"` <--- no space

on converting it to entity framework using `ToList()` or as `IEnumerable()`; e.g.

```cs
var _BANKS = dbcontext.BANKS.IEnumerable();
//var _BANKS = dbcontext.BANKS.ToList();
```

Just note that I have to put this on a `Memory` because I constantly refer to this table as reference.

On simple execution

```cs
string bankcode  = "xxxxxx    ".Trim();
var test = _BANKS.Where(q => q.BCODE == bankcode ).ToList(); // <--- would return me null

var test2 = from t in _BANKS where t.BCODE == "xxxxxx" select new t; <--- still null
```

but when I change the `_BANKS` as `AsQueryable();` using the same code snippet above, it would give the desired result the same on the native query (see first SQL snippet).

I'm avoiding the `.AsQueryable()` because it will give me a runtime error specifically
`"The specified LINQ expression contains references to queries that are associated with different contexts."`
because I'm using it to constantly refer in a different DBContext's.

Comment: It's not weird, it's how SQL server works:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17876478/why-the-sql-server-ignore-the-empty-space-at-the-end-automatically

The lookup on the memory array does not exhibit this behaviour, which is why your lookup fails.
You can always do `_BANKS.Where(q => q.BCODE?.Trim() == bankcode )` to workaround this.

Comment: Thanks for your response your link is so helpful @zaitsman but the workaround `q.BCODE?.Trim()` did not work as well. I also did a lot of trimming before I made this post.

Comment: I assume that `[BCODE]` is defined as a `char` datatype in SQL?

Comment: @Jason it's a VARCHAR(6, null) and the `bankcode` is form a VARCHAR(12, null) if it matters.

Comment: Ok ... question. Why are you using `dbcontext.BANKS.IEnumerable()` instead of simply `dbcontext.BANKS` without  `ToList()` or `ToEnumerable()`?

Comment: hi @Jason the same reason why I'm avoiding the `AsQueryable()` thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you check how the result values appear in your list? If they are there with spaces, then you should search with spaces..

Comment: I get the impression that not all the information required to solve this is in the question you posted. The error `"The specified LINQ expression contains references to queries that are associated with different contexts"` usually occurs when you combine two separate LINQ queries from two separate `DBContext` objects. But that shouldn't prevent you from using `AsQueryable()` on one, and calling `ToList()' on the result which you could then use it in the other `DBConext` Query.

Comment: @Jason you are right, I actually have another `working workaround` for this problem which is slower. but I'm baffled why ToList() and IEnumerable() can't have the same result with a simple `string` query, don't you think?. and should've been a better approach in my case in my opinion. using `Memory` as a recurring reference instead of the DB context itself.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why in case of a simple SQL statement, you got one result is pretty obvious for me:
it is that in the database, you have a record which contains spaces, i.e. 'xxxxxx    '.

Now why it is not working when using the below code?:

```cs
string bankcode  = "xxxxx    ".Trim();
var test = _BANKS.Where(q => q.BCODE == bankcode ).ToList(); // <--- would return me null

var test2 = from t in _BANKS where t.BCODE == "xxxxxx" select new t; <--- still null
```

Because you are trimming the `bankcode` which will lead to converting "xxxxx   " to "xxxxx" but in the database, you have an actual record matching this "xxxxx   ". That's why it will return `null` which means it will not find matching records.

To overcome this issue use LINQ to SQL `Contains()` method:

```cs
string bankcode  = "xxxxx    ".Trim();
var test = _BANKS.Where(q => q.BCODE.Contains(bankcode)).ToList();
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your time. I already tried this and weirdly this has the same results. in the BANKS database, it has a varchar(6) so there are no spaces.

Comment: If it is indeed limited to 6 characters, adding anything after the 6th, like `where t.BCODE = 'xxxxxx    '; <--- with spaces`, is pointless and just adds to the confusion.

Comment: Hi Andrew. ` 'xxxxxx    ';` <--- with spaces  i put this because I would like to emphasize that this is from different dbcontext varchar(12) to be exact.( I'm sorry if it made it more confusing.) --- and thus querying it to native SQL would give the expected result. as explained here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17876478/why-the-sql-server-ignore-the-empty-space-at-the-end-automatically that said I'm aware that tolist and ienumerable does not have the same mechanism that `asqueryable` have. that's why we included a `trimming` in the second snippet.

Comment: @JuliusLimson I know this might seem a bit trivial, but did you check the database record("xxxxx") to contain only English "x" records?

Comment: @ArsenKhachaturyan hi, i know what you mean. xxx is just an alias to hide real code but yes, i did check.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was not in the `.ToList()` or the `.IEnumerable`, but rather it is related to a memory leak when you are trying to save the data in the `Memory` from a `Table view`.

Workaround

```
var _BANKS = (from banks in dbcontext.BANKS
             select new {
              banks.BCODE,
              // ... so on.
             }).ToList();
```

`re-selecting` the LINQ from storing into your `Memory` weirdly corrects the inconsistency.

Comment: That sounds quite weird. Did you find any documentation about that memory leak?