# Why ignoring space text in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server

When I compared text like this:

```
'a' = 'a '
```

the result is True - but I was expecting it to be false.

Do you know why the result is true? And can I do something to solve this issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why the SQL Server ignore the empty space at the end automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17876478/why-the-sql-server-ignore-the-empty-space-at-the-end-automatically)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`DATALENGTH()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datalength-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Example

```
SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE DATALENGT('a') = DATALENGTH('a ')
```

`DATALENGT('a')` return the result as 1
and `DATALENGTH('a ')` return the result as 2, includes the space text.

Please check the [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=69178a4430be019498ae201d29db20da) for reference.

Answer (score 0):

The LIKE operator does not pad the trailing spaces:

```
SELECT * FROM basePath WHERE 'a' LIKE 'a '
```

More information can be found here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/56876/sql-server-auto-trim-of-varchar-value-in-equal-comparison-but-not-like-compariso